# Converting succession type from Gavelkind to Primogeniture in early game

Tags: crusader-kings-2

My character controls the Grand Prinicipality of Kiev and various counties, whose succession type is Gavelkind. I wish to convert it to Primogeniture but I require level 3 Legalism. Is there a faster or easier way to convert my succession type?

Comment: Does it have to be Primogeniture or do you just need to get rid of Gavelkind?

Comment: I need to get rid of Gavelkind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to get Primogeniture but you lack the necessary Legalism level to raise your Crown Authority until it fulfills the requirement, then there are 3 options I am aware of:

- (Dukes and Counts only) Move your capital to a county which de-jure belongs to a kingdom which wasn't created yet. This removes the crown authority requirement and by extension the Legalism requirement.
- Acquire Legalism 3 by moving your capital to a county which already progressed so far. When you switch to the Technology window and move your cursor around the map you can see the tech levels in different counties. But it might be difficult to find a county with Legalism 3 nearby, because due to the way technology spreads in the game, nearby counties will have similar levels of technology.
- Acquire a second title of your current rank which already has primogeniture and make it your primary title.

But if you just want to prevent your realm from splitting apart due to too many sons, consider the other succession forms where one heir inherits everything:

- Ultimogeniture (all to youngest son)
- Seniority (all to oldest living dynasty member)
- Elective Monarchy (all to whoever your vassals like best - might also be one of them, though)

Also, keep in mind that **Gravelkind succession is often not as bad as people think**. Unless you have more than one title of your highest rank (multiple duchies if you are a duke, or multiple kingdoms if you are a king), your brothers won't become independent. They will get some of your previous character's counties. But unless they somehow managed to gain independence before daddy kicked the bucket, they will hold them as your vassals. Also, you will be their heir until they have kids on their own. So if any "accidents" happen to your brothers, you will get their counties. You can gain more time by marrying them to a woman beyond childbearing age (>45) or bethroth them to some little baby girl. You can also prevent people from mating by making them councillors or commanders and send them on missions away from home (not 100% reliable because it doesn't prevent other characters from knocking up their lonely wifes at home and they being unable to prove it).

Or you can just revoke your brother's titles. The opinion penalty with your other vassals will go away after 5 years ([and can even be avoided altogether under some circumstances](https://ck2.paradoxwikis.com/Title_revocation#Revocation_reasons)). The Kinslayer trait does not. And if he rebels? Even better. Beat him and you get to revoke a second title for free and can let him rot in your prison until he dies.

Or you can just let them keep them and fill up your demesne cap by conquering some new lands.